# Communicate with python process

Tags: python, linux, bash, input, output

I have a python prog which does something like that:

```python
while (true) {
    Number1 = input("What's your first number?")
    Number2 = input("What's your second number?")
    print("Your numbers are: ",Number 1, Number 2)
    Sum= input("Whats the sum?")
    if Sum == Number1 + Number2:
        print("You win")
        exit()
    else print("You failed, try again!")
}
```

this is obviously not the exact code, it's just for an understanding of what it does; it's more complicated than just sum, I won't be ale to calculate it and will need to retry more than once. I can't change that python script, just execute it.

I want to write a script that would give him the first two input, get back what's printed, then give him third input, get back what's printed. And start again, until I win.

This is on a linux box where I don't have many rights, with python3.6

I've tried two methods:

- Using a bash script and a python script together: Bash script call my python script and the main one, and use an output file and pipes to transfer input/output. It doesn't sound like a proper way to do it, but it "mostly" works (I can always see the first round, sometimes it goes further). Spent yesterday afternoon on that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Create temporary files for communication
output_file=$(mktemp)
# Trap to ensure cleanup of temporary files on script exit
cleanup() {
    rm -f "$output_file"
}
trap cleanup EXIT
# Run the Python scripts with temporary files
python3 /tmp/tmp1/crack.py < "$output_file" | /path/to/python/prog > "$output_file" &
# Wait for the background process to finish
wait
# Display the contents of the output file
cat "$output_file"
```

crack.py:

```python
#Python file: go get input, send output, construct password.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

sum = ""
answer = ""

while not "You win" in answer:
    print(0)
    print(3)
#Weirdly, works better if I comment the input() lines.
#    input()
#    input()
    sum += input()[10]
    print(sum)
#    answer = input()
```

EDIT: If I comment ALL the input() lines (including `sum += input()`) then it works, but obviously I have to change the while loop because I can't check the ending condition, so I have to do a fixed number of loops, randomly chosen. All the output from the python prog will be in the output file, and since it does print my two first input it's sufficient for what I need to do, but it really bother me that I can't properly handle the prog output and react accordingly to it.

- Using only another python script with subprocess method (spend the morning reading doc about it):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import subprocess
import sys
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

p = Popen([sys.executable, '/path/to/main/python/exec'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input="1\n200\noops\n")
print(stdout)
p.kill()
```

Doesn't work at all. Looks like the process is running in background and I'll get the output when, and only when, it terminates. Definitely not what I want. Also, it sends back encoding errors (even if I put the encoding arg in popen, it says that some received output from the main script is not utf-8). I've tried p.stdout instead of communicate too (looks like communicate is from python3.7 anyway), and subprocess.run instead of popen, but it looks like the behaviour of this thing is to run wait for subprocess to terminate before getting output anyway so won't do what I want.

I tried using coproc too, but it's not installed on the machine (and I can't install anything).

What would be the proper way to handle input/output of the python prog?

Comment: Look into expect

Comment: I did, but as I said it's a basic linux machine where I can't install tools. There's no coproc, and no expect either.

Comment: What prevents you using `pip install --user` which only affects your HOME directory but no other system users?

Comment: there is no home directory for the users. /home is empty. It's a challenge box, to be used by many challenger; you can write only by creating a dir in /tmp. Note that my question is not how to solve the challenge; I solved it already, I wanted to solve it in a more automatic & graceful way